# Can be called from main thread Error in working with events for server Listeners in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i use QuObject source for connecting to socket io server for sending and getting Listenrs (emits).
like this :

```
socketConnection = IO.Socket("127.0.0.1:3000");
socketConnection.On(QSocket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
  onConnectedSocket();
}
```

and this is my codes for creating delegate and event :

```
public delegate void SocketConnectionListener(); 

public event SocketConnectionListener OnSocketConnectionListener;
protected virtual void onConnectedSocket() => OnSocketConnectionListener?.Invoke();
```

and when i want to use this event for handling the connection through another script i get error in this like

```
ConnectedMsg.SetActive(true);
```

the error is this :

```
SetActive() can only be called from the main thread.
```

so how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Call it from the main thread?

Comment: yes , the error said it should be in main thread 
how can i do that woth this structure?